# How can i restrict access to a service running on a particular port on a Windows Server?

Tags: ip, windows-services, port, windows-firewall

I currently allow access to a service on a Windows Server as follows:

```
http://<server_ip>:<port_number>
```

When the user enters this in the browser it takes them to a UI on the Windows Server

Note: the user machine are on a DHCP Server so ip addresses can change.

How can i restrict access only to certain users ?
Is there a way i can force them to enter a name or secret as a querystring parameter and resolve on the Server side ?